# ExternalContext#redirect() with includeViewParams=true

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, viewparams

Using a list of currencies in the form of strings as follows.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="currency"
                 value="#{currencyRateBean.currency}"
                 onchange="changeCurrency([{name: 'currency', value: this.value}]);">

    <f:selectItems var="row"
                   value="#{currencyBean.currencies}"
                   itemLabel="#{row}"
                   itemValue="#{row}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Along a `<p:remoteCommand>`.

```
<p:remoteCommand ignoreAutoUpdate="true"
                 name="changeCurrency"
                 partialSubmit="true"
                 process="@this"
                 update="@none"
                 action="#{currency.currencyAction}"/>
```

The managed bean setting a currency value being passed through the above `<p:remoteCommand>` as a parameter to a JavaScript function.

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Currency {

    @Inject
    @HttpParam
    private String currency;

    @Inject
    private CurrencyRateBean currencyRateBean;

    public Currency() {}

    public String currencyAction() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new URL("http://www.exchangerate-api.com/INR/" + currency + "/1?k=FQRxs-xT2tk-NExQj").openConnection().getInputStream(), "UTF-8");) {
            currencyRateBean.setCurrencyRate(scanner.nextBigDecimal());
            currencyRateBean.setCurrency(currency);
        } catch (UnknownHostException | ConnectException e) {}

        return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true&includeViewParams=true";
    }
}
```

The supplied currency value is then set to another session scoped managed bean `CurrencyRateBean` from within the action method `currencyAction()` above which finally makes a redirect based on the current value of `viewId` along with `includeViewParams=true` which is important.

---

Now, the story changes, when `#{currencyRateBean.currencies}` has been changed to have a list of composite objects which has been a list of Strings so far.

The following scenario will not work with `includeViewParams=true` which is significant.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{currencyRateBean.currencyHolder}">

    <f:selectItems var="row" value="#{currencyBean.currencies}"
                   itemLabel="#{row.currency}"
                   itemValue="#{row}"/>

    <p:ajax event="change"
            listener="#{currency.currencyAction}"
            partialSubmit="true"
            process="@this"
            update="@none"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

```
public void currencyAction()  throws IOException {
    // ...
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String viewId = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId();

    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect(externalContext.getRequestContextPath() + viewId + "?includeViewParams=true");
}
```

<sub>`includeViewParams=true` has been added for decoration only. It is not going to work.</sub>

Since `listener` in `<p:ajax>` is incapable of making a redirect based on a navigation case outcome as done by `action` of `<p|h:commandXxx>`, `ExternalContext#redirect()` has to be used anyway.

`<p:remoteCommand>` can be used on complete of `<p:ajax>` but this will involve two round trips to the server unnecessarily, first to set the currency value to the associated managed bean and then to make a redirect.

How to make a redirect with `includeViewParams=true` in the example given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like `faces-redirect=true`, `includeViewParams=true` works only in navigation outcomes, not in "plain" URLs which you pass to `ExternalContext#redirect()`.

Use [`NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/NavigationHandler.html#handleNavigation-javax.faces.context.FacesContext-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
String outcome = viewId + "?includeViewParams=true";
context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, null, outcome);
```

Or, with [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/2.2/org/omnifaces/util/Faces.html#navigate-java.lang.String-).

```
Faces.navigate(viewId + "?includeViewParams=true");
```

A dubious alternative is to collect all view parameters yourself and convert them to query string so you can use `ExternalContext#redirect()` anyway. This is easier with OmniFaces.

```
Faces.redirect(viewId + "?" + Servlets.toQueryString(Faces.getViewParameterMap()));
```

Comment: I cannot remember where I read but somewhere I read that `NavigationHandler#handleNavigation()` is an old practice of JSF 1.x. Is it? Therefore, I did not think of using it.

Comment: Explicit navigation cases as in `<navigation-case>` things in `faces-config.xml` is old practice.